# Tengo un error al crear una tabla SQL state: 42601

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, postgresql, tablas, state

Estoy creando las tablas de una base de datos, pero me sale un error de sintaxis en una de ellas y no logrado descifrar el error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
create table work(
work_id integer not null,
work_name varchar(150) not null,
description varchar(200),
worker_amount integer,
primary key(work_id));
```

Answer (score 0):

Se me ocurren dos posibles solucinones:
El posible fallo en tu codigo es que al estar la palabra key pegada al paréntesis el programa no te reconozca la palabra key como la palabra reservada que es.

```
create table work(
work_id integer not null,
work_name varchar(150) not null,
description varchar(200),
worker_amount integer,
primary key (work_id));
```

Y otra solucion sería poner la primary key directamente en la misma fila tal que asi:

```
create table work(
work_id integer PRIMARY KEY not null,
work_name varchar(150) not null,
description varchar(200),
worker_amount integer
);
```